# how to make a 'backspace' program in C?

Tags: c, assembly

I am creating some library function for print and scan using assembly language and c.
Now when am entering datas it is getting print,but the problem is when i press the backspace button the cursor is moving backwards(but not deleting anything)..I want the backspace button to work properly(ie,to delete the previous character)

so is there any program for that.Please help me.

Comment: If you're collecting key presses, then you have to handle the deletion yourself, if you're using scanf then it would handle it for you. Add code, show what you tried.

Answer (score 2):

The simple, albeit somewhat hackish, way is to just write backspace characters (`\b`) to the console.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Testing");
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("\b\b\b");
    fflush(stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

But this type of thing should really be handled by your terminal driver. You don't mention what operating system you're targeting in the question.

Comment: Thank u cody gray,but i want the backspace button to work normaly..That is i want the code to delete the previous character when we hits the backspace button

Answer (score 0):

Output a backspace, space, and backspace:

```
int c = getchar();
if (c == '\b')
{
    printf("\b \b");
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

If the user's press of a backspace was already echoed by the terminal driver then just do this:

```
int c = getchar();
if (c == '\b')
{
    printf(" \b");
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Comment: What's the point of a backspace, space, and a backspace? That seems like 2 steps too many.

Comment: Whatever character the user pressed before the backspace, you want to stop displaying that character, so you need to display a space instead.  Is that 2 steps too many?  Notice that fewer steps don't solve this issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

if u r doing so then would like to tell you one thing abt consoles
There are 2 types of consoles , one which can recognize control char. called 
Active console(Canonical mode) and one which not called row console .
Obviously if u r using unix's terminal then u will be given default as Active mode console
but u can set it to row mode by executing some commands.